# shopware sample website is not redirecting to checkout page

Tags: shopware

I have installed a version of shopware 5 in my local development server and installed a demo plugin to list the sample products. After adding products to the shopping cart and create user, it is not redirecting to shipment or payment page.

If i check database, i can see that the user has been created. But  trying to login with that details, the website just reloads the page and not redirecting to account or shipping page. What could be the issue.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: maybe you can provide more information about your changes. Obviously this isn't the normal behavior.

Comment: Other than installing the plugin for sample products, nothing has been installed. just set it up  and tried to checkout. but cant  login/reach checkout page

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it is working.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with `function sCheckUser()` in `/engine/Shopware/Core/sAdmin.php`.
Here the **timeOut query** creating the problem. Either remove timeOut checking from querying or fix accordingly. *(Not recommended to modify core files.)*

Comment: @BernadVicky If the answer is useful, please do upvote or accept the answer.